# What does the rank of a matrix of linear constraints tell us?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Suppose we have a constraint matrix $M = (\mathbf{a_1}, \dots, \mathbf{a_n})$, where $\mathbf{a}_i \in \mathbb{R}^k$ are row vectors (i.e. each $\mathbf{a_i}$ is a row in the $n \times k$ matrix $M$). Let the solution space $S$ be defined as all $\mathbf{y} \in \mathbb{R}^k$ such that $\mathbf{a_i}^\top \mathbf{y} \geq 0$ for all $i \in \{1, \dots, n\}$.

My question is what the rank of the matrix $M$ tells us about the dimension of the solution space $S$.

When the constraints are of form $\mathbf{a}_i \mathbf{y} = 0$, then I believe it is true that $dim(S) = k -rank(M)$. Can something similar be said when we have constraints $\geq$?

Answer (score -1):

The solution set of $Ax=b$ is just a translation of the solution set of  $Ax=0$. So their dimensions as geometric objects are equal since it might not even be a subspace.

$ \textbf{RMK} $.Both sets lie on the domain. If your matrix is $n \times m $ the domain is $\mathbb{R^m}$ and your codomain is $\mathbb{R^n}$ So if you know which $x$ solve $Ax=0$ since A practically is a linear function to find which $x$ solve $Ax=b$ find a specific $x_0$ and translate all the previous $x$ +$x_0$ . These two sets must have the same dimension im just translating. So all you need is rank-Nullity theorem.

Comment: Thanks. A clarifying question: So you are saying that the solution space $S = \{ \mathbf{y} : \mathbf{a}_i^\top \mathbf{y} \geq 0\}$ can be viewed as a solution space of the inhomogeneous set of equations $Ax = b$? I.e. $Ax \geq 0$ is in terms of the dimension of the solution space the same as $Ax = b$?

Comment: IF you have $n \times k$ matrix all $y$ in $\mathbb{R^k}$ such that $Ay=b$ are the same elements of all $y' $ in $\mathbb{R^k} $ translated to a specific solution $Ay_0=b$ . All the solutions of $Ay=b$ are ${ y+y_o}$ such that  y is solution to Ay=0 and $y_0$ specific solution to$ Ay=b$ What you can get from  is that this  is the Nullspace but i have added one vector to all elements.

Comment: Now this may not be even a subspace of $R^k$ since it may not even have zero  in it. So i cant tell its dimension since it is not even a linear space (but as a geometric object will look similar if the nullspace is a line then the solutions of  Ay=b will be a line translated).

Comment: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/linear-algebra/matrix-transformations/inverse-transformations/v/linear-algebra-exploring-the-solution-set-of-ax-b